# inline styling CSP violation tawk.to embedded chat widget

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy, tawk.to

I am using Tawk.to's chat widget codes on my website to enable the chat bubble. I simply put the code inside a JS file :

```
var Tawk_API = Tawk_API || {}, Tawk_LoadStart = new Date();

(function() {
var s1 = document.createElement("script"), s0 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s1.async = true;
s1.src = 'https://embed.tawk.to/xxxxxx/default';
s1.charset = 'UTF-8';
s1.setAttribute('crossorigin', '*');
s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1, s0);
})();
```

I am requiring it in a HTML file as a `<script>`. It works as intended. But the issue is that the code below causes my website to violate some Content Security Policies. For my content security policies, I am not allowing any inline styling, for security reasons. And apparently, the 'https://embed.tawk.to/xxxxxx/default' does contain some inline styling. Is there a work around for that without allowing inline styling on my website?

Answer (score 0):

Tawk.to's widget has so much  of inline styles in tags and inline styles blocks, so to use a 'hash-value' to allow those is not practically realizable.

The only way is to iframe this widget to isolate from main page CSP, if is suitable.

> For my content security policies, I am not allowing any inline
> styling, for security reasons

What about 'unsafe-inline' in script? It's much unsafe than in style-src.
You could allow inline script of widget itself with 'nonce-base64value' token, but Tawk.to's widget uses javascript:-navigation, so without 'unsafe-inline' in script-src you'll have a CSP violations too. Do click on smile icons ans look into browser console.

Comment: Hi @granty, I am not allowing `'unsafe-inline' in script either. In fact, I am not allowing unsafe-inline anywhere. For the way that you recommended, how do I embed the chat widget as a iframe exactly?